# Is there a nuance of meaning between "could" and "would" when asking someone to do something politely?

Tags: difference, modal-verbs

Could you tell me if there is a nuance of meaning between *could* and *would* when asking someone to do something politely? For example:

> Kate, **could** you pick up some milk on your way home?
>
> Kate, **would** you pick up some milk on your way home?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could you vs would you](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129843/could-you-vs-would-you)

Comment: There really isn't enough difference for it to be worth trying to learn this, but in at least *some* contexts, a native speaker *might* think that the ***could*** version is slightly more "deferential / tentative". Much more importantly, they're not always "interchangeable" on purely syntactic grounds. You can ask someone ***Would you mind helping me**?*, for example, but you *can't* validly ask ***Could you mind helping me**?*

Comment: The answer at Colleen V's link is wrong. elliotcm's one-liner below is better

Answer (score 1):

There's a very very slight nuance, but I'd say it's more a pattern of speech than anything significant.