# Can/Should we use "of" after "let me know"?

Tags: word-usage

Can we place "of" after "let me know"? If we can either include or drop it, which construction is preferred?

As an example, which of the following sentences is preferred?

1. Can you please let me know the requirements needed to apply?
2. Can you please let me know **of** the requirements needed to apply?

If the use/drop of "of" depends on the context, I would appreciate it if you could elaborate a bit on it.

Comment: Where is the "know"? To [know of](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/know-of) something is different from "[let know](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/let-someone-know?q=let+know)" something.

Comment: @ColleenV Oops. I added the "know"s. Great insights! I guess my question is in the second usage you mentioned ("let know"), can/should we add "of"?

Comment: You could phrase it *Could you please tell me the requirements to apply?* Sometimes adding more words makes it more polite/formal, but in this case a simple "please" is enough. I'm on the fence about Could you... or Would you... it depends on the context. I guess I will read this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/129843/9161 to decide :)

Answer (score 1):

Drop it. 'Of' is a preposition that shows relationship or membership.
You're simply supplying a direct object. No preposition necessary to link the verb and object together.

Comment: Thank you! There are cases where "of" is _not_ used before a direct object. Here is an [example](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/know-of). But I think this usage does not apply to the example sentences I provided above. Please let me know if I did not get it right.

Comment: You're right that there are cases where "know of" is appropriate, although I will point that the "of" is not necessary (the sentence is grammatical and reads fine without it) in those cases either.

The difference is subtle, but I think the distinction is this: in your case, "the requirements" is not part of what you "know". When you "know of something", the "something" does have membership of what you "know".

Comment: Thank you for the additional information!